# Definition of multiplication in a complex field

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

In a complex field, the definition of multiplication is $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$. Is it possible to use an alternative definition of multiplication and still retain all the defining properties of a field?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586139/uniquely-determining-complex-multiplication) might be of interest. If you want certain properties to still hold, it will be unique. If not, I suspect there are ways to define   multiplication that still results in it being a field.

Comment: Yes it is. If you consider any bijection between complex and real set (they are both continuum cardinality so you can do it), then you define sum and multiplication for any to complex numbers as sum and multiplication for corresponding real numbers.

Or you need to keep sum definition unchanged?

Comment: Presumably you want $(0,1)^2 = (-1,0)$ as well?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I'd like to change the definition of multiplication, changing or keeping the definition of addition, so that (a,0)+(b,0)=(a+b,0) and (a,0)(b,0)=(ab,0) remain true and all field properties are retained. And I would like the square of (0,1) not to be (-1,0). Is that possible? If so, can anyone give me an example of how it can be done?

Comment: I've found an answer to my question. Definition of multiplication:                               (a,b)(c,d)=(ac+2bd,ad+bc).Definition of addition unchanged. We still have                       (a,0)+(b,0) = (a+b,0), and (a,0)(b,0)=(ab,0).Now (0,1)(0,1) = (2,0), so now (0,1) corresponds with sqrt (2) instead of i. All field properties still apply.